# Is it possible to change an external website through google sheets?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I just made my first useful program (javascript) last week, but it was exhilarating to realize that *I never have to to this repetitive **** again*. So bear with me, since I might ask a simple question.

I'd like to, from google sheets, create separate page for each client listed in the sheet, on my wordpress page.

Is that possible?

It's a simple question, but it might save me countless of hours figuring out how, if there's actually no way.

Comment: Have you tried? If so, what have you tried? This is not an advice/code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets cannot do it by itself, but you can make a program which will download data from Google Sheets API and then by WP REST API create posts on your Wordpress site and put data as content.

Link to [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/)

You can also make Wordpress site download data from Sheets and then create posts.

There is a third option: make Google Apps Script which will operate on Sheets and on WP REST API.

Comment: Great, thanks Ronin, you did not only give an "yes" but also pointed me in the right direction! I'll check out WP REST API, and hopefully, with a lot of trial and error, I can get it to work!